# Can you set CIFS permisions from EMC Command Line?

Tags: network-share, file-sharing, cifs, emc

I am in the process of migrating file shares from my EMC NS-20 to my new VNXe 3100. I am using a RoboCopy script to move the files but am getting errors on some files and folders. I have Domain Admin privileges but when I go to view the security permissions on the folders it says I don't have permissions. I have tried taking ownership to get around the permissions issue but that fails too. So as a last resort can I set permissions on this folder from the EMC console or Web management console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot modify the permissions of a share from the Control Station or from the Celerra Management interface. (This may seem like a dumb thing, but for those of us that ONLY manage the storage it's a boon!)

When you create a share, it should initially come up with Everyone/Everyone permissions.  Are you sure you're a full domain admin?  I've run into issues where my "Domain Admin" account wasn't actually in the Domain Admins group and I was not able to set permissions.